# Is OpenGL just for graphics when it come to game design?

Tags: opengl

I am a computer science major interested in learning how to create games. I know c++ very well and I am familiar with opengl. I want to know if opengl is just for graphics or can it be used for things like networking, collision detection, and sound for designing a game?

Comment: If you are familiar with OpenGL then you know that it is simply a graphics API, all OpenGL does is let you draw pictures.

Comment: So what will I have to learn if I want to make a game?

Comment: The "GL" stands for "graphics library", and any OpenGL specification will tell you: "OpenGL is a software interface to graphics hardware".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is just for drawing graphics. It cannot help you with any of the things you mention, eg networking, collision detection, sound, etc.

Look for a game engine in C++ that uses OpenGL and has facilities for those sorts of things.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a Graphics [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). It provides functions and methods for rending high performance graphic images; more information [here](http://www.opengl.org/).

However, things like collision can be implemented for use with OpenGL rendered objects using third party libraries or, of course, you can write you're own, which isn't recommended seems it would take too long; there are already many resources available; one that comes recommended is [Havok](http://www.havok.com/products/physics) or there is [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) for real-time simulation, (you might have more luck asking questions about collision using bullet [here](http://www.bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/)).

There are also cross-platform Audio APIs like [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) for example.

Ideally, you would just use a third party games/physics engine and include it's libraries much like you would include OpenGL libraries.